# How to implement operator < for an arbitrary struct to use in STL data structures?

Tags: c++

I sometimes want to use keys in map and set that contain more than one value. I don't care too much about speed. Is there an easy or general way to write operator < to compare structs with multiple values? I've come up with the following on my own but it is tedious, especially as the number of values increases. Thanks.

```
struct Properties
{
    Properties() {}

    Properties
        ( const string& data1
        , const string& data2
        , const string& data3
        )
        : data1(data1)
        , data2(data2)
        , data3(data3)
    {}

    string data1;
    string data2;
    string data3;

    bool operator < (const Properties& other) const
    {
        if (this->data1 == other.data1)
        {
            if (this->data2 == other.data2)
            {
                if (this->data3 == other.data3)
                {
                    return false;
                }
                else
                {
                    return this->data3 < other.data3;
                }
            }
            else
            {
                return this->data2 < other.data2;
            }
        }
        else
        {
            return this->data1 < other.data1;
        }
    }
};
```

Answer (score 4):

You can use `std::tie` for this:

```
#include <tuple>

bool operator<(Properties S& rhs) const
{
  return std::tie(data1, data2, data3) < std::tie(rhs.data1, rhs.data2, rhs.data3);
}
```

This works, independent of the types of the `dataN` (provided they have an `operator<`).

Answer (score 1):

It does get rather tedious.

Of course, if you store your data in an array [assuming all the data is of the same type], you could use a loop:

```
const int numstrings = 3;
string data[3];

...

bool operator < (const Properties& other) const
{
   for(int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
   {
      if (data[i] != other.data[i])
      {
          return data[i] < other.data[i]; 
      }
   }
 }
```

Of course, you can also shorten your existing code a bit:

```
bool operator < (const Properties& other) const
{
    if (this->data1 != other.data1)
    {
        return this->data1 < other.data1;
    }
    if (this->data2 != other.data2)
    {
        return this->data2 < other.data2;
    }
    return this->data3 < other.data3;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You may try to convert them to tuples, and them compare them. That would replace your `Properties` class.

Answer (score 0):

You could do it in a more flat way like this:

```
bool operator < (const Properties& other) const
{
    if (this->data1 < other.data1)
        return true;
    if (other.data1 < this->data1)
        return false;

    if (this->data2 < other.data2)
        return true;
    if (other.data2 < this->data2)
        return false;

    return this->data3 < other.data3;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The traditional way to do this is as follows

```
bool operator<(Properties const& lhs, Properties const& rhs) const
{
    return (lhs.data1 < rhs.data1)
           || (!(rhs.data1 < lhs.data1) && lhs.data2 < rhs.data2)
           || (!(rhs.data1 < lhs.data1) && !(rhs.data2 < lhs.data2) && lhs.data3 < rhs.data3;
}
```

This has the advantage of working for all types with `operator<` defined, rather than relying on `operator==`.

Comment: It has the disadvantage of not working, though. For instance, `{3, 3, 1}` would compare less than `{2, 2, 2}`, which is probably not what OP is looking for.